# kickstart does not chmod a file in %post section

Tags: centos, rhel, executable, chmod, kickstart

I have the following code executed in the `%post` section of a kickstart file for RHEL 6.6.

```
echo '#!/bin/sh' > /root/add_user
echo 'if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then echo "no username provided"; exit 1; fi' >> /root/add_user
echo 'set -e' >> /root/add_user
echo 'useradd $1 -g foo -G wheel,dialout,sshusers -m' >> /root/add_user
echo 'passwd $1' >> /root/add_user
chmod +x /root/add_user
```

The file is created correctly however is not chmoded with executable permissions. I have a log file as well for the post section and no error is reported in terms of the `chmod` command or any other errors at all. I can not figure out why the file is unable to be set to have executable permissions, any idea why this may be happening?

**UPDATE**

When I do a verbose `chmod` I get the following in the log

```
mode of /root/add_user retained as 0755
```

Comment: What permissions does `/root/add_user` end up with? If it's really 0755, it's already executable.

Comment: I actually just found the answer but won't be helpful to anyone not locking down a machine, after I set the file to be executable another rpm would execute that got rid of execute in all of the root folder. So the solution was to change the chmod to the end of the kickstart.